# text field and button alignment

Tags: html, django, forms, layout

I have a Django Form like this :

```
class FriendrequestMixinForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout (
            Row (Div('email', css_class="col-md-6"), FormActions (Submit('submit', 'Add'), Button("cancel", "Cancel"))))

        super(FriendrequestMixinForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The buttons are aligned like this :

[Example Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x1dp.png)

How can I align the buttons at the bottom of the Email Field in one row

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
class FriendrequestMixinForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = "form-group"
        self.helper.layout = Layout (
            Row(Div('email', css_class="col-md-6")),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Add'),
                Button("cancel", "Cancel")            
            )

        )

        super(FriendrequestMixinForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: Updated so that the buttons are aligned with the email field, and with everything in one row.

```
class FriendrequestMixinForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = "form-group"
        self.helper.layout = Layout (
            FieldWithButtons('email', 
                Submit('submit', 'Add'),
                Button("cancel", "Cancel") 
            ),
        )

        super(FriendrequestMixinForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. This results the button and the textfield in two separate rows. I want them to be in one row. As this is only a secondary form.